# Angular 2 tutorial 'Tour of heroes' , a lot of files Eclipse in Project Explorer after compile

Tags: eclipse, angular

At the moment I'm learning Angularjs 2 through the tutorial 'Tour of heroes' Typescript. So far so good. But I've noticed something when doing this tutorial. It's about the files that are created after the compiling with NodeJs. A lot of files are appearing and I'm curious if you guys have some advice for how to organise these files.

[image: A list of files!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `"outDir"` property in your `tsconfig.json` and make it point to the folder you want:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build"
    }
}
```

this will output all compiled `.js` and `.map` files to the `./build` folder.

Comment: This is getting close, but I've still got problems. When compile it would go to './build' folder. But the tutorial needs css and html files to load. Somehow when I do npm start nothing works anymore. I think it because the path issue and the missing files that's in the app-folder. Is there anyway to solve this issue when i use 'npm start' command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question answered combining information from n00dl3 and some information of this page "[angular 2 adjust System.config() after separate javascript files and typescript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975620/angular-2-adjust-system-config-after-separate-javascript-files-and-typescript?rq=1)".

The issue with html and css, you can just copy/paste these files in the './build' folder. Or just give other path where the html and css are located at:

```
 @Component({ 
    templateUrl:'/example-folder-path/file.html' //this is the line
  })
```

Comment: seems like styleUrls: [array] has a bug. see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4974